# python convert to yaml formatting issue

Tags: python, yaml

I have the following simple script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import yaml    

returns = {'file_|-/usr/bin/gen-motd.py_|-/usr/bin/gen-motd.py_|-managed': {'comment': 'File /usr/bin/gen-motd.py updated', 'pchanges': {'diff': '--- \n+++ \n@@ -1,5 +1,7 @@\n #!/usr/bin/env python\n \n+import sys\n+import urllib2\n import socket\n import json\n import time\n'}, 'name': '/usr/bin/gen-motd.py', 'start_time': '16:18:54.060168', 'result': True, 'duration': 99.663, '__run_num__': 1, 'changes': {'diff': '--- \n+++ \n@@ -1,5 +1,7 @@\n #!/usr/bin/env python\n \n+import sys\n+import urllib2\n import socket\n import json\n import time\n'}, '__id__': '/usr/bin/gen-motd.py'}}
returns = yaml.dump(returns, default_flow_style=False)
print returns
```

Its outputting

```
file_|-/usr/bin/gen-motd.py_|-/usr/bin/gen-motd.py_|-managed:
  __id__: /usr/bin/gen-motd.py
  __run_num__: 1
  changes:
    diff: "--- \n+++ \n@@ -1,5 +1,7 @@\n #!/usr/bin/env python\n \n+import sys\n+import\
      \ urllib2\n import socket\n import json\n import time\n"
  comment: File /usr/bin/gen-motd.py updated
  duration: 99.663
  name: /usr/bin/gen-motd.py
  pchanges:
    diff: "--- \n+++ \n@@ -1,5 +1,7 @@\n #!/usr/bin/env python\n \n+import sys\n+import\
      \ urllib2\n import socket\n import json\n import time\n"
  result: true
  start_time: '16:18:54.060168'
```

The diff part is badly formatted.. I want it to return something like

```
file_|-/usr/bin/gen-motd.py_|-/usr/bin/gen-motd.py_|-managed: 
  __id__: /usr/bin/gen-motd.py
  __run_num__: 1
  changes: 
    diff: |
        --- 
        +++ 
        @@ -1,5 +1,7 @@
         #!/usr/bin/env python

        +import sys
        +import urllib2
         import socket
         import json
         import time
  comment: "File /usr/bin/gen-motd.py updated"
  duration: 99.663
  name: /usr/bin/gen-motd.py
  pchanges: 
    diff: |
        --- 
        +++ 
        @@ -1,5 +1,7 @@
         #!/usr/bin/env python

        +import sys
        +import urllib2
         import socket
         import json
         import time
  result: true
  start_time: "16:18:54.060168"
```

Comment: Did you try "\n" in double quotes

Comment: I don't have control of what comes out to be set into `returns`

Comment: you can have a regex to replace all \n by "\n"

Comment: yes that didn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems to overcome to get this as you want:

- your lines cannot have spaces before the newline, as there is no way to represent that in literal style scalars
- you need to provide a routine that outputs strings with newlines as literal style scalars or use a YAML library that supports that format, like ruamel.yaml (disclaimer: I am the author of that package).

Using `ruamel.yaml` is the far more easy way, just convert strings that are 3 levels deep and contain a newline:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import LiteralScalarString

returns = {'file_|-/usr/bin/gen-motd.py_|-/usr/bin/gen-motd.py_|-managed': {'comment': 'File /usr/bin/gen-motd.py updated', 'pchanges': {'diff': '--- \n+++ \n@@ -1,5 +1,7 @@\n #!/usr/bin/env python\n \n+import sys\n+import urllib2\n import socket\n import json\n import time\n'}, 'name': '/usr/bin/gen-motd.py', 'start_time': '16:18:54.060168', 'result': True, 'duration': 99.663, '__run_num__': 1, 'changes': {'diff': '--- \n+++ \n@@ -1,5 +1,7 @@\n #!/usr/bin/env python\n \n+import sys\n+import urllib2\n import socket\n import json\n import time\n'}, '__id__': '/usr/bin/gen-motd.py'}}

for k in returns:
    for k1 in returns[k]:
        if not isinstance(returns[k][k1], dict):
            continue
        for k2 in returns[k][k1]:
            v = returns[k][k1][k2]
            try:
                if '\n' in v:
                    while ' \n' in v:
                        v = v.replace(' \n', '\n') # remove EOL spaces
                    returns[k][k1][k2] = LiteralScalarString(v)
            except TypeError:
                continue

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(returns, sys.stdout)
```

You can of course remove the whole `for` construction and use

```
returns = {'file_|-/usr/bin/gen-motd.py_|-/usr/bin/gen-motd.py_|-managed': {'comment': 'File /usr/bin/gen-motd.py updated', 'pchanges': {'diff': PreservedScalarString('---\n+++\n@@ -1,5 +1,7 @@\n #!/usr/bin/env python\n\n+import sys\n+import urllib2\n import socket\n import json\n import time\n')}, 'name': '/usr/bin/gen-motd.py', 'start_time': '16:18:54.060168', 'result': True, 'duration': 99.663, '__run_num__': 1, 'changes': {'diff': PreservedScalarString('---\n+++\n@@ -1,5 +1,7 @@\n #!/usr/bin/env python\n\n+import sys\n+import urllib2\n import socket\n import json\n import time\n')}, '__id__': '/usr/bin/gen-motd.py'}}
```

Either way this gives you:

```
file_|-/usr/bin/gen-motd.py_|-/usr/bin/gen-motd.py_|-managed:
  start_time: '16:18:54.060168'
  comment: File /usr/bin/gen-motd.py updated
  duration: 99.663
  __id__: /usr/bin/gen-motd.py
  changes:
    diff: |
      ---
      +++
      @@ -1,5 +1,7 @@
       #!/usr/bin/env python

      +import sys
      +import urllib2
       import socket
       import json
       import time
  __run_num__: 1
  pchanges:
    diff: |
      ---
      +++
      @@ -1,5 +1,7 @@
       #!/usr/bin/env python

      +import sys
      +import urllib2
       import socket
       import json
       import time
  name: /usr/bin/gen-motd.py
  result: true
```

Because you are using `dict` the order of the keys in the YAML file is undetermined. You can construct `returns` directly with `CommentedMap` instances (from `ruamel.yaml.comments`) and `PreservedScalarString` and have control over the key orderings in your YAML mappings as well.